# Programmatically edit the end point of a web service

Tags: .net, web-services, configuration, console-application

Is there a way I can programmatically change the `<endpoint address="..." />` value of a web service?  In my app.config file, I have the following code:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
       ...
   </bindings>
   <client>
     <endpoint address="http://dev.remotedomain.com/WebServices/WebService.asmx"
         binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InboxServiceSoap"
         contract="InboxServiceSoap"
         name="InboxServiceSoap" />
   </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I want to be able to change

```
address="http://dev.remotedomain.com/WebServices/WebService.asmx"
```

to

```
address="http://mymachine/WebServices/WebService.asmx"
```

in code. Is this possible progammatically in .NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use code similar to the following:

Dim service as new XXXXXClient
service.Endpoint.Address = New EndpointAddress(myUrl)

Comment: This works but makes me suspicious.  After adding a WCF Service Reference there are a half dozen project file that reference the service URL.  I then move the service to a different URL, add this line of code, and everything works fine.  Seems like it shouldn't compile???

Comment: @nuander Compilation is fine, just a string is different. As long as the different URL complies to the same protocol and format, no runtime problems either.